# Getting error code 4220 with null SQL State

Tags: db2, spring-jdbc

I'm getting error code -4220 with null SQL State .the SP "XXXXX" contain VARGRAPHICS data type. Below is complete exception stack trace. SP is executing properly, the error is coming while reading output parameter i.e. execute method called successfully but getString method is giving error.

Even if I'm trying to access any method to get output parameter value, error is coming. Just FYI, I tried with latest version of db2 driver but still error persist.

```
    com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][1065][12306][3.65.77] Caught java.io.CharConversionException.  See attached Throwable for details. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.cd.a(cd.java:682)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.cd.a(cd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.cd.a(cd.java:112)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gc.a(gc.java:2825)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gc.a(gc.java:582)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gc.q(gc.java:560)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gc.N(gc.java:1557)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gc.a(gc.java:1541)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.CallableStatement.D(CallableStatement.java:941)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.CallableStatement.getString(CallableStatement.java:920)
    at com.cst.test.daoLayer.SPTest.callDB2ProcOUTParameter(SPTest.java:118)
    at com.cst.test.daoLayer.SPTest.testLogic(SPTest.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.executeMethodBody(TestMethodRunner.java:99)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runUnprotected(TestMethodRunner.java:81)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runMethod(TestMethodRunner.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.run(TestMethodRunner.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.invokeTestMethod(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.run(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:35)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner$1.runUnprotected(TestClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner.run(TestClassRunner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 5
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.r.a(r.java:19)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gc.a(gc.java:2821)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: sun.io.MalformedInputException
    at sun.io.ByteToCharUTF8.convert(ByteToCharUTF8.java:278)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.r.a(r.java:16)
    ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using latest version of jar and by setting below system property .

```
System.setProperty("db2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder", "3");
```

Also another way is disable unicode encoding for char and varchar type in DB2 SP which also worked for me ..

Comment: How to "disable unicode encoding for char and varchar type in DB2 SP",  can you please explain.

Answer (score 7):

After experiencing this same error, it turned out that older versions of the db2jcc jar do not support Java 8. After reverting to Java 7, the error goes away. This can also be resolved by downloading the newer/supported version of the jar from IBM.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research I found the exact jars to be downloaded to solve the CharConversionException.
To be specific. This issue is resolved in the JDBC v9.7 Fix pack 5. This release addresses APAC74895 (which solves the CharConversionException) so that special characters in the db are skipped rather than an exception being thrown.

[You need to download the appropriate jar from the IBM site](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866)

Then add the following environment variable(Java VM arguments) in ur tomcat settings
     -Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3

Thats it problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

We encountered this problem after changing DB columns from CHAR to VARCHAR. The problem was resolved after restarting our Java WAS Server - apparently the DB2 driver needs a restart to cope with this.

Answer (score 0):

db2jcc.jar driver is now deprecated.

Identify your db2 version and include the latest db2jcc jar file to your build path.

In my case : Db2 version = 9.7.301.326 and i added

```
db2jcc-9.7.4.jar
```

Refresh and rerun your application.It worked for me.

For more details : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the problem as my db2jcc jar was obsolete and my server was pointing to the obsolete jar for getting db2 connection.

Updating the db2jcc jar resolved my issue.