# How to check the character encoding of a table or column in DB2?

Tags: character-encoding, db2

How to check the character encoding of a table or column in DB2?

I have strange characters appearing in certain records in a DB2 database and I was wondering how I could check for the current character encoding set for the table or column.

[image: Strange characters]

Because of it, I'm receiving an error. Here's the stack trace.

```
Exception: [jcc][t4][1065][12306][3.64.106] Caught java.io.CharConversionException.  

See attached Throwable for details. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][1065][12306][3.64.106] Caught java.io.CharConversionException.  See attached Throwable for details. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:663)
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:60)
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:112)
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fc.a(fc.java:2825)
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fc.p(fc.java:525)
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fc.N(fc.java:1562)
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ResultSet.getStringX(ResultSet.java:1147)
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ResultSet.getString(ResultSet.java:1122)
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ResultSet.getString(ResultSet.java:1698)
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at PersonalInventionHistory.inventorDetail(Unknown Source)
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at PersonalInventionHistory.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM: Caused by: 
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 3793
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.r.a(r.java:19)
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fc.a(fc.java:2821)
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   ... 9 more
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM: Caused by: 
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM: sun.io.MalformedInputException
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at sun.io.ByteToCharUTF8.convert(ByteToCharUTF8.java:293)
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.r.a(r.java:16)
01/14/2014 01:44:44 AM  HTTP JVM:   ... 10 more
```

Comment: That depends on the DB2 platform and version. You may also want to describe in detail how you have determined that __strange characters__ appear in the database, and not as an artefact of the client you're using.

Comment: Agree with @mustaccio - I've looked into this sort of data before - from one client I had an accented y, and the other an accented i.  This behavior _may_ have had some impact in the results in copying to Notepad (been too long to remember exactly)...  Since I was looking for "unusual" characters I didn't bother figuring out which one was correct (by examining the bytes and checking encoding tables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16910791/1746868) plus added well placed try and catch blocks solved my problem.