# Hibernate BigDecimal Conversion Error for Different Numbers

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, db2

I have a test class which inserts into table successfully when I try with `BigDecimal fazlaBulundurmaOrani = new BigDecimal(6000);`. However, this test fails for different BigDecimal values such as `BigDecimal fazlaBulundurmaOrani = new BigDecimal(15000);`

Here is my test case:

```
@Test
public void testGetDepoFazlaById() {
    DepoTur depoTur = new DepoTur("my tür", 5);
    depoTurService.saveDepoTur(depoTur);

    List<DepoTur> list = depoTurService.getDepoTurList();
    assertNotNull(list.get(0));

    BigDecimal fazlaBulundurmaOrani = new BigDecimal(6000);
    DepoFazla depoFazla = new DepoFazla(1, list.get(0), fazlaBulundurmaOrani);
    depoFazlaService.saveDepoFazla(depoFazla);
}
```

Here is the hibernate reference in the model:

```
@Column(name = "FAZLABULUNDURMAORANI", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(6, 2)")
@Type(type = "big_decimal")
private BigDecimal fazlaBulundurmaOrani;
```

Here is how I create database:

```
CREATE TABLE PGMTEMS.TDEPOFAZLA
(
    ID DECIMAL(20,0) GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
    GRUP INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DEPOTUR DECIMAL(20, 0) NOT NULL,
    FAZLABULUNDURMAORANI DECIMAL(6, 2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

I get this error when I try with different BigDecimal numbers:

> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate
>   operation: could not insert: [tr.gov.tcmb.pgmtems.model.DepoFazla];
>   uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into PGMTEMS.TDEPOFAZLA
>   (ID, DEPOTUR, FAZLABULUNDURMAORANI, GRUP) values (default, ?, ?, ?)];
>   SQL state [null]; error code [-4220];

Comment: What database are you using? Google for <database name> and the error code -4220. For example, "mysql error code -4220", if you're using MySQL.

Comment: I'm using DB2. I have tried searching but couldn't find.

Comment: Belki db2 jarlarından kaynaklanıyor olabilir

Comment: Bir de böyle bir şey var sizin hataya benziyor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910791/getting-error-code-4220-with-null-sql-state

Comment: In your setter method of fazlaBulundurmaOrani can you try setting the scale ie this.fazlaBulundurmaOrani = fazlaBulundurmaOrani.setScale(2);

Comment: @Periklis I have tried setting the scale as you mentioned but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set `FAZLABULUNDURMAORANI DECIMAL(6, 2)` so it can have values like 9999,00. 15000 has more than four digits, therefore it gives an error.