# Required character converter is not available. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null

Tags: java, database, db2, db2-luw

The application I migrate to Java8 was running on Java7. After the migration i had to update the db2jcc.jar to latest version and yet I have the error below:

```
Required character converter is not available. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null
```

I have checked and tried the topic [Getting error code 4220 with null SQL State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910791/getting-error-code-4220-with-null-sql-state)

```
My DB version : DB2 v10.5.0.11
The db2 Jar I use : db2jcc-9.5.jar
```

Has anyone faced this before?

Regards

Comment: Your question states "db2 Jar I use : db2jcc-9.5.jar" .  If you __really__ are using that version, it is the cause.  When you get the exception text in full, it will show the jdbc driver version. You should be using db2jcc4.jar at version `4.19.80` (or higher) and that string should appear in the exception text.

Comment: @mao Hi, my full exception text is [Camel Thread #2 - JmsConsumer[null]] WARN **** - SQLException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: [jcc][t4][10199][10462][3.52.95] Required character converter is not available. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null  . I am a bit confused, version of what `4.19.80` I should be using jcc4.jar?

Comment: The exception text shows that you are using jdbc driver driver version 3.52.95 (which is supplied with db2 v9.5 fixpack 2a). Please try with a currently supported type-4 db2 jdbc driver, which you can download via  https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads

Comment: @mao I've updated it as you said to type-4. I need to keep running the application to see if its okay for sure but seems like so far so good. I think this solved the problem. Thank you. If you write your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question included

```
My DB version : DB2 v10.5.0.11
The db2 Jar I use : db2jcc-9.5.jar
```

The exception text included:

```
     [Camel Thread #2 - JmsConsumer[null]] WARN **** - SQLException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException:

 [jcc][t4][10199][10462][3.52.95] Required character converter is not available. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null
```

Notice the db2 jdbc driver version, `[3.52.95]` included in the exception text.
This is an old driver that comes with db2 version 9.5 fixpack2a, long out of support.

You need to be using a recent type 4 jdbc driver for Db2, and the version of the db2 jdbc driver will appear in the exception text as a three part number with a dot separating the parts.

For Db2-LUW v10.5 the currently available version of the db2 type 4 jdbc driver is `4.19.80`  although you can use higher versions.

You can download the recent jdbc driver versions from this IBM [website](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads), you will need to register with IBM first, although the download is free.